# Why can't time.In() get the right time in the time zone America/New_York

Tags: go, timezone

Here is my code

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func main() {
  tz := "America/New_York"
  loc, err := time.LoadLocation(tz)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  fmt.Println(time.Now().In(loc))
}
```

And it supposed to get the result like this [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XUmf_vgWXC)

```
2009-11-10 18:00:00 -0500 EST
```

The weird thing is that it prints out the `UTC` time instead of `EST` when trying to run it on my server

```
2017-11-22 14:53:16.94672706 +0000 UTC
```

---

Some environments

```
go version go1.8.3 linux/amd64

Linux version 3.10.0-514.21.2.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-037.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sun May 28 17:08:21 EDT 2017

GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/root/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build674699918=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

Comment: Never omit errors, do check the returned error: `loc, err := time.LoadLocation(tz)`

Comment: @icza But there is no error

Comment: There is no error on the Go Playground, but I'm asking about your local computer where it does not work.

Comment: I did check the error on my server. There is no error retured

Comment: This should work just fine, are you sure what you've posted is what you are running?

Comment: That's because [NY *is* in EST currently](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/new-york), so it works as expected.

Comment: Are you rebuilding this on the server? If so, why? Have you tried building locally and deploying the binary to the server?

Comment: @kostix UTC time is the unexpected result

Comment: @FrankBryce I tested it on my local linux virtual machine and it works as expected. The server which got the weird result is an AWS server. I posted some system info. I thought it may have sth to do with the zoneinfo.zip file in the go lib dir .So i replace it with the file in my local machine which has the  same go version but with no luck. And the most interesting thing is that other time zone name works just fine.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, I built it locally and copy the binary to the server.Then run it and got he UTC time. So may be there is something wrong with the OS?

Comment: I believe on Linux, Go uses the system's tzdb; it only uses Go's built-in tzdb on Windows. So it could be an issue with the tzdb (or missing tzdb) on the server. Try a `sudo yum update tzdata` on the server and see if it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I've tested locally, and it returned EST. 1.8.3 on linux/amd64.

Comment: Are you running your program in a chroot environment or in a stripped-down container or on a system otherwise missing the Olson TZ data? Too tight SELinux or AppArmor or whatever policy may be?

Comment: @Adrian I update the tzdata and it works. Thanks

Comment: @Adrian Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the system `tzdata` package is out of date

```
sudo yum update tzdata
```

This command fixed the problem, as suggested by @Adrian